# how use get_user_meta with like?

Tags: wordpress, sql-like

I try to do this in wordpress:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `ZGCxrEcMusermeta` where meta_key like 'CoursRL_%'
```

In wordpress I start with:

```php
$TOne = get_user_meta($user_id, 'here my query', 'true');
```

All my next queries need to be like this.

Can someone help me?

Comment: grammar and formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested but you can try like this

```
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {

    $where .= "AND meta_key like 'CoursRL_%'";
    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

$args = array(
    'suppress_filters' => false
);

$TOne = get_user_meta($args);
```